# Can I use nc and/or stunnel to make a transparent SSL proxy such that I can specify the outgoing source port?

Tags: linux, proxy, netcat, stunnel

I've been playing around a bit with different variations and can't seem to find something that quite works.

I want to be able to 'bridge' an SSL connection across a particular gateway node in the network. In particular I want to further be able to control the outgoing source port for the TCP connection.

I can use stunnel for part of this -- to bridge the SSL connection. I know I can use `nc` to set the source port for a connection, but how might I connect these two together to allow specifying the source port for the outgoing connection? (Or is there an alternative solution here I should be considering?)

---

I feel like if I can get `nc` to work as a transparent proxy this will be fine, since I can set the source port with it. I feel like I may just be missing something about how `nc` works. So just to provide a little more context, here's what I'm trying. Suppose I've got an SSL server running locally on 1235. I want to connect to it with an SSL client, but I want to make sure my outgoing source port for the connection is always, say, 1234. (I can connect directly with the client, but I'm given an arbitrary high-number port; I need to be able to specify it.)

My thought was trying to use `nc` as a bridge here, with something like:

```
# nc -l localhost:1234 | nc localhost:1235
```

This definitely establishes proxies *something* -- I see traffic flowing between the right endpoints -- but it doesn't seem to handle the SSL very well at all. The secure link won't get established and I can't actually communicate between the two using openssl client/server.

What might I need to do to get this working? I'm going to try to determine if stunnel can assist me here; I was thinking that between the two of them I might be able to get this working.

---

Alright, I have played with `socat` a little bit, which does seem to bridge the connection -- but I can't seem to figure out how to specify the source port. Any thoughts?

Comment: A transparent proxy provides proxying without needing to specify the proxy settings in the client.  Is this something you want also - you don't touch on it in the description.

Comment: I must ask *why* is specifying the source port required? This is highly unusual for TCP connections, especially when the requested port is "arbitrary". If this is required by a firewall, then said firewall should be thrown out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes used by `|` are one-way. When you run `nc | nc`, the second connection's output goes to *your terminal*; the first connection's input is read from your keyboard. Basically, the full form of it would be `</dev/tty nc | nc >/dev/tty`.

To create a bidirectional tunnel, you would have to use something else, such as...

```
socat tcp-l:localhost:1234 tcp:localhost:1235
```

(Or create a named pipe and use it with two `nc`'s, but that's less efficient.)

---

However, that will *not* do what you want. It will not make 1234 become the source port of the second connection; you will only have it as the *destination* port of the *first* connection, and the two connections are unrelated: `stunnel` simply receives bytes from both connections and resends them to the opposite end.

If you want simply to specify the source port of a connection, it's simpler:

```
nc -l 56789 localhost 1235

socat stdio tcp:localhost:1235,sourceport=56789
```

Since `stunnel` does not have a "local port" option, you can take one of the above commands and use it in the `exec=` option.